# I do not know how to activate register for foreign key in relationship in the database

Tags: python, django

I'm Brazilian then in the table `Veiculo == vehicle` and `Pessoa == person` and as a person can have several cars plus one car only one person, when registering a new monthly `checkin` in the parking lot, I need to select the person only the cars that he own appear as an option. I need that when registering a `Pessoa` and a `Veiculo` they are `realacionamos` in a way that when registering using Views `Mensalista` when I put `Pessoa` `soment` the Veiculo that is owned by it appears

in a forum gave me the idea to use the code below, but I do not know how to implement it

```
proprietarioId = id
queryList = Veiculo.objects.filter(proprietario__id = proprietarioId)
```

Models.py

```
TATE_CHOICES = (
('AC', 'Acre'), ('AL', 'Alagoas'), ('AP', 'Amapá'),
('AM', 'Amazonas'), ('BA', 'Bahia'), ('CE', 'Ceará'),
('DF', 'Distrito Federal'), ('ES', 'Espírito Santo'),
('GO', 'Goiás'), ('MA', 'Maranhão'), ('MT', 'Mato Grosso'),
('MS', 'Mato Grosso do Sul'), ('MG', 'Minas Gerais'),
('PA', 'Pará'), ('PB', 'Paraíba'), ('PR', 'Paraná'),
('PE', 'Pernambuco'), ('PI', 'Piauí'), ('RJ', 'Rio de Janeiro'),
('RN', 'Rio Grande do Norte'), ('RS', 'Rio Grande do Sul'),
('RO', 'Rondônia'), ('RR', 'Roraima'), ('SC', 'Santa Catarina'),
('SP', 'São Paulo'), ('SE', 'Sergipe'), ('TO', 'Tocantins')
)


class Pessoa(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, blank=False)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.nome) + ' - ' + str(self.email) 


class Veiculo(models.Model):
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marca, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    ano = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    placa = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    proprietario = models.ForeignKey(
        Pessoa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, )
    cor = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)


def __str__(self):
    return self.modelo + ' - ' + self.placa
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def mensalista_novo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MensalistaForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('core_lista_mensalista')
    else:
        form = MensalistaForm
    return render(request, 'core/lista_mensalistas.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: dou want get all the Veiculo of a Pessoa

Answer (score 0):

you have to do from the form fronend side using whenever Pessoa will change write a jquery function which call one end point to get all the Veiculo associates with Pessoa

```
$("#Pessoa fields id").onchange(function(){

      $ajax({
        url:"",
        data:{"id":$("#Pessoa fields id").val()},
        method: get
      })
 })
```

then define one view

```
def get_veiculo(self, request, *args, **kwarsg):
    proprietarioId = request.GET.get('id')
    queryList = Veiculo.objects.filter(proprietario_id = proprietarioId).all()
    return render('option.html', request, {'Veiculo':queryList})
```

option.html

```
{% for data in Veiculo %}
  <option value="{{data.id}}">{{data.modelo}}</option>
```

Comment: Hi friend, I am very newbie, I understood the def and I put it in Mensalista, but on the jquery and the option.html I did not understand how and where to put them